# Is app with SPFx version 1.4.1 compatible with SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

Is app with SPFx version 1.4.1 compatible with SharePoint Online?

I deployed SPFx app of version 1.4.1 and it has problem to sometimes load the web part and sometimes not, is it because of version compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**.

All features and all versions of SharePoint framework (SPFx) are supported by SharePoint Online.

[image]

**Microsoft Documentation**: [SharePoint Framework development tools and libraries compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility)

---

**Additional**:

You can also upgrade the SharePoint framework solution/project to the specified version (latest) for SharePoint online using CLI for Microsoft 365.

Check: [spfx project upgrade](https://pnp.github.io/cli-microsoft365/cmd/spfx/project/project-upgrade/)

Comment: Do you have maybe some idea why my app is loading on Sharepoint Server 2019 without problems but for that app when deployed on Sharepoint Online webparts are sometimes loading and sometimes not?

Comment: Do you get any errors in browser console when web parts are not loading?

Comment: It tries to find webpart build files in https://mySharepointsite.com/mySubsite/ClientSideAssets/AllItems.aspx, and they're not there - because we use CDN path. When the webparts are loaded, it takes them from CDN path, and when they're not it tries to find them in ClientSideAssets where they're not